# What is the word to describe people who require a wheel chair?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the most precise word for this condition?

Comment: what is the new euphemism?

Comment: @BigCatPublicSafetyAct isn't the new euphemism not to label such people? It would undo all the progress that's been made to de-stigmatise them. Like speaking to them slowly and loudly.

Comment: Defining *this* as a condition leaves us nowhere to go that's good. Just saying.

Comment: You mean someone who uses a wheelchair, someone who uses a wheelchair and cannot manage without one, or someone who needs a wheelchair to be mobile but does not necessarily have one?

Answer (score 4):

**Wheelchair user** or **person in a wheelchair**: They're neutral and need no definition. Here's some examples in use:

- [Fitness advice for wheelchair users](https://www.nhs.uk/live-well/exercise/exercise-guidelines/wheelchair-users-fitness-advice/)
- [What are Problems that Wheelchair Users Face?](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.karmanhealthcare.com/what-are-problems-wheelchair-users-face/amp/)
- [How to evacuate a person in a wheelchair](https://escape-mobility.com/how-to-evacuate-a-person-in-a-wheelchair/)
- [How to Ask Someone in a Wheelchair If They Need Help](https://actionseating.net/blog/how-to-ask-someone-in-a-wheelchair-if-they-need-help/)

It's neutral because it doesn't make any assumptions about why a person is using a wheelchair. Many people who use wheelchairs are able to walk (and hence aren't "wheelchair bound") but choose to use a wheelchair because it is very painful to walk.

I'm listing two terms here because one is an identity-first term ("wheelchair user") and the other is a person-first term ("person in a wheelchair"). According to the [APA](https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/bias-free-language/disability):

> Both person-first and identity-first approaches to language are designed to respect disabled persons; both are fine choices overall. It is permissible to use either approach or to mix person-first and identity-first language unless or until you know that a group clearly prefers one approach, in which case, you should use the preferred approach.

In fact, the APA lists both terms too.

Comment: One *could* argue that "wheelchair user" is a bit too essentializing to be completely neutral, and instead opt for "persons using wheelchairs" as they do here: [Washington State Legislature Americans with Disabilities Act Information](https://leg.wa.gov/legislature/Pages/ADAInfo.aspx)

Comment: @Juhasz Like many subgroups in the disability community, there doesn't seem to be a preference here between identity- and people-first language.

Comment: Only minor problem with this is that a person who requires a wheelchair but has not received one couldn't really be a *wheelchair user*. So if the OP works to provide people with wheelchairs, it may not be the best term.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the word to describe people who require a wheel chair?

The normal term is "obligate wheelchair user". This distinguishes people who are not able to walk from those, like my 96-year old mom, who have very limited range, endurance, and ability to deal with obstacles when walking; and who frequently use wheelchairs.

The distinction is important in describing and assessing barriers to accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

They have an **accessibility need**, specifically for a wheelchair.

The Wikipedia page for [accessibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accessibility) states

> Accessibility is the design of products, devices, services, vehicles, or environments so as to be usable by people with disabilities.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accessibility) has

> **accessibility**
> 5 : easily used or accessed by people with disabilities : adapted for use by people with disabilities

This term is being used because it isn't in itself a label or judgement about a person. It simply means that facilities are easily accessible by anyone, including those with physical, visual, hearing, etc.,  impairments.

Comment: The problem with this suggestion is that it is not specific to wheelchairs, which was the point of the question.